# Overload boost::multiprecision::pow with fixed precision

Tags: c++, overloading, pow, boost-multiprecision

The following code

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<50>, boost::multiprecision::et_off> float_50; 

int main()
{
    float_50 a = boost::multiprecision::pow((float_50)5, (float_50)10); // works
    double b = boost::multiprecision::pow((double)5, (double)10);       // doesn't work

    //double b = boost::multiprecision::pow<double>((double)5, (double)10); // Why can't be overloaded?
    return 0;
}
```

won't compile since `boost::multiprecision::pow` does not recognised fixed precision type. What is the usual solution for this? I'd rather have a single `pow` function which accepts both multi and fixed precision types. It is strange to me that boost constants, for instance, have template definitions so

```
boost::math::constants::pi<double>()
boost::math::constants::pi<float_50>()
```

work fine. Shouldn't `boost::multiprecision::pow` also be overloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) is to leave off the namespace.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<50>, boost::multiprecision::et_off> float_50; 

int main()
{
    float_50 a = pow((float_50)5, (float_50)10); 
    double b = pow(5., 10.);      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ADL here is intentional: You want to use the libc version of pow if possible (for speed), and only use the higher-precision multiprecision::pow when using multiprecision types.

Comment: I was caught out because usually we have this paranoia about being specific with which functions and namespaces we call and so on.

Comment: It's a sensible paranoia, only to be overridden for good reason.

Comment: If you look at the constants, they are long text strings which are then parsed and rounded to the precision.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way for a single function to handle arguments of different types.  You need a separate function for each supported parameter set.  The function may be autogenerated from a template—but `pow` does not seem to be a candidate for a template implementation.